# Asp .net web application is not creating a scripts folder which usually contains bootstrap and jquery scripts

Tags: .net, web-applications

My Visual studio is not automatically making a "scripts" folder whenever I creates a ASP .net web application[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4fGk1.png)

Comment: Microsoft Visual Studio Community 2019
Version 16.10.4

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is due to the project template you selected.

The ASP.NET Core project templates have bootstrap and jQuery removed, which is why you do not see the Scripts folder.

If you choose "traditional" templates which contains `(.NET Framework)` in template name, such as the `ASP.NET Web Application (.NET Framework)` template, then you will see the Scripts folder:

[image: traditional template with Scripts folder]

A rule of thumb is that all project templates with `(.NET Framework)` target the full .NET Framework and behave the same as the pre-.NET Core age.